# Google Analytics Cookies Affected by Analytics Plugins

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-analytics, e-commerce, universal-analytics

I have a site which uses Google's "Universal" `analytics.js` script.

I'd like to enable demographic reporting (which is an official Google plugin) but demographic reporting uses a 3rd party cookie (loads from the "Double Click" domain) which means that users, like myself, that block 3rd party cookies and/or use Ad Blockers may not load the script and be recorded.

I read all the seemingly relevant posts on here, and I have [seen conditional Javascript which tests if it loads and then falls back to the standard script](http://andrescholten.net/google-analytics-retargeting-for-adwords-and-adblock-software/).

I've also had experience where our developers used the "[synchronous script](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/asyncMigrationExamples)" for e-commerce tracking (they recycled code from a site where they had set it up previously) on a site that otherwise used the "async" tracker; it caused all e-commerce transactions to be attributed to 'direct.'

If I use the google "plugin" for demographic reporting (with a fallback or not) and then only on the checkout pages use the "plugin" for e-commerce tracking but not demographic reporting (tracking e-commerce data is more important than demographic stats) will this cause me any problems?

How would it be handled?

Does every part of the script need to be identical on every page (i.e. should I load the e-commerce plugin on every page)?

I with every modification and plugin I'd use the snippet would look like this:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', {'siteSpeedSampleRate': 100});  //track page load speed 100% of time, rather than default 1%
  ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js'); //e-commerce plugin
  ga('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js'); //plugin to track multiple links to the same destination separately
  ga('require', 'displayfeatures'); //enable demographic reporting
  ga('send', 'pageview'); 
</script>
```

E-commerce takes precedence over demographics so I'd likely remove the demographic reporting plugin from the cart.

There aren't multiple links to the same page in the cart (only to the cart) so `linkid.js` could be removed while in the cart and there is no e-commerce tracking needed until you get into the cart.

Adding and subtracting all these plugins seems dicey to me, does anyone have experience with this or see any obvious problems?

Answer (score 0):

I think the right way is

```
  ga('require', 'displayfeatures', 'linkid', 'linkid.js');
```

Comment: Providing some explanation will improve your answer